# How to print the node taxonomy in a block?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-theming

I'd like to print taxonomy terms (from field `field_tags`) in a block on a node view page (in a Zen subtheme).

So what I did was.

`template.php`

```
function michal_preprocess_block(&$vars, $hook) {
 if ( arg(0) == 'node' && is_numeric(arg(1)) ) {
   $node = node_load(arg(1));
   $vars['node'] = $node;
   $vars['node_field_tags'] = $node->field_tags;
   $vars['node_content_field_tags'] = $node->content['field_tags'];
 }
}
```

However, when I try to print it in `block.tpl.php`, neither of these 2 variables outputs taxonomy terms from the field.

```
print render($node_content_field_tags);
print render($node_field_tags);
```

**Do You know a Drupal function to render a taxonomy terms field?**

---

EDIT 13.01.2011, 00:21

As far as I understood (from [this](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.module/function/node_view/7), [this](http://drupal.org/node/339929#comment-1182561) and [that](http://drupal.org/node/722294#comment-2638028)) the process the code should look more/less like this

```
 $node = node_load(arg(1));
 $node_view($node) // Generates an array for rendering a node, see http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.module/function/node_view/7
 $vars['node'] = $node;
```

and then in the `block.tpl.php`:

```
render($node->content['field_tags']);
```

The $node->content is null, however.

**Do You know what I'm missing?**

Comment: can't you simply create a view to display the taxonomy contents within the block instead of modifying the template?

Comment: Hi, unfortunately I need to have it in code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've come across the solution I was looking for:

mytheme_preprocess_block() in *template.php**

```
$node_content = node_view(node_load(arg(1)));
$vars['node_content'] = $node_content;
```

.

*block.tpl.php*

```
print render($node_content['field_tags']);
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually what may be easier is the following code in your preprocess:

```php
if ($node = menu_get_object()) {
  $vars['node_field_tags'] = field_view_field('node', $node, 'field_tags', 'full');
}
```

And then use the following in your template:

```
print render($node_field_tags);
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should check that the preprocess function is being run and that cache is not playing with you. Then you could try to inspect the variables. I don't think you can use `render()` on the `$node->field_tags` and I'm not too sure about `$node->content['field_tags']` either.

Inspecting the variables will help you figure it out, devel works fine for Drupal 7 and can help you there.

Comment: Hi googletorp, 1) the preprocess function is called - other code from this is executed, 2) I've already looked into the variables and `$node->content['field_tags']` (if I remember well) gives the array of terms that I can extract and format of course, but I was looking more for a built-in function that would deliver a standard output for a given taxonomy field. Something similar to `render()`. --> Maybe I'll investigate the how views treats such fields.

Comment: @Michal You probably want to use `theme('field', $varaibles)` for the field for a standard markup generation.

Comment: thanks. That was probably this. Could You please give me a sample call? `theme('field', $node->field_tags)` is missing something and http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--theme.inc/function/theme/7 is quite unclear to me. Before, I did theming by extracting raw values from an array, but as a new year resolution I'd like to do it the Drupal way. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You might also check out the [CCK Blocks module](http://drupal.org/project/cck_blocks). It creates a sidebar block that displays alongside each node (if it has content), and adds that block to the list of rendering destinations for each field, just like 'teaser' and 'full' and 'rss'.

It may not have all the control you're looking for but it could be a good place to start.

Comment: Thanks Eaton, the code of the module You suggested gave me some hint to solve the issue. :)